# why downvoted in this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Anyone have an idea Why I was downvoted in this question?
I really don't know.

[How can I prove $\pi_1(M)=\pi_1(M-\{q\})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244912/how-can-i-prove-pi-1m-pi-1m-q)

Thanks

Comment: Seems I can't cancel that close vote - sorry about that, I was lost and thought I was on main. Only realised when it didn't give me a migrate option.

Comment: @MattPressland why I was downvoted? just to know

Comment: There is rarely anything to be gained in pursuing reasons for downvoting. See the "Related" questions along the right side of this page --- some of them refer to downvoting behavior.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, but I disagree because knowing the reason for downvoting helps us to improve our questions and answers

Comment: @Rafael That wasn't me, so I can't say. Mine was an unintended vote to close because I got confused and thought you'd posted on the main site, so I was trying to get the question migrated to meta.

Comment: With 2 down votes and 7 up votes, I say: don't worry about the down votes.

Comment: Rafael, let me expand: there is rarely anything to be gained in pursuing reasons for downvoting because (among other things) it hardly ever results in knowing the reason for downvoting. And even that is assuming a fact not in evidence, namely, that there actually was a reason for downvoting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I understand, thank you :)